# Backing up Ubuntu to a hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, backup

What is the best program for backing Ubuntu up to a hard drive?

Comment: This guy ^ I'm not a fan of this guy. Posting possible duplicate.  Just kidding bro.

Comment: Have a look behind the link he provided, useful info.

Comment: I thought the irony was obvious.